# Why does this VBA code break Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to attach a hammer image onto the mouse cursor on Excel. It works fine without the Do Loop, that is it moves the image close to the mouse cursor when I run the macro using a button on sheet1. The problem starts when I try to make the image follow the cursor on-the-fly, using a Do Loop. In the past, I was able to make that happen without any errors, but I did not save that Excel workbook. Now, I am trying to do it again and it crashes Excel every time. I might get lucky and get a "Left method of object failed" or a "Top method of object failed" error, but that does not really help. Here is the VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Sub MoveHammer()

    Dim lngStatus As Long
    Dim typWhere As POINTAPI
    Dim activate As Boolean
    activate = True

    Do While activate = True
    lngStatus = GetCursorPos(typWhere)

    Sheet1.Shapes("hammer").Left = 0.75 * (typWhere.x - 77)
    Sheet1.Shapes("hammer").Top = 0.75 * (typWhere.y - 274)
    Loop
End Sub
```

"hammer" is the name of the picture object that I have inserted. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to kludge this yourself instead of just using `SetCursor()`. You seem to be aware of the WinAPI, because you're using it for `GetCursorPos()`.

Comment: @JohnColeman OMG YES! How can I be so blind and naive? Of course I would need a DoEvents statement. Thank you so much! Type this as a response so I can mark it.

Comment: @KenWhite the reason is because I do not want to set the cursor to a certain position. I simply want to have that image follow the cursor. So I am grabbing the position of the cursor with GetCursorPos().

Comment: I didn't say `SetCursorPos()`. I mentioned `SetCursor()`. They don't do the same things. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VBA lacks multithreading, in order to get responsiveness while inside of the loop you will need a `DoEvents` inside of the body of the loop.